# How to estimate the number of decimals places needed for exponentiation?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

I'm working on an application that requires arbitrary precision calculations. There is no power function for computing a number to the power of another. However, there are functions for computing `exp(x)`, `mul(x, y)` and `ln(x)`, so I'm using the identity `x ^ y = exp(y * ln(x))` to compute exponentiation. The functions allow me specifying the number of decimals (scale) as the precision. For example: `ln(x, 10)` will return a result precise up to the 10th decimal place.

The question is: how to compute the number of decimals places needed for computing the exponentiation precise up to a given scale? In other words, given the function `pow(x, y, s)`, where `x` is the base, `y` the exponent and `s` the scale (number of decimal places), what should be the value of `s1` in such way that the result will be exact up to the `s`th decimal place?

`pow(x, y, s) => exp(mul(y, ln(x, s1), s1), s1)`

Comment: Is your error scale relative or absolute? If it is relative (and small of course) then $\exp(z)$ has a relative error of $\epsilon$ provided $z$ has an absolute error a little bit less than $\epsilon$. If it is absolute then the problem is more difficult. Usually people stick to relative error in these kinds of things. (Incidentally, I'm sure such a library as this one already exists and is probably even open source.)

Comment: I'm using bcmath that requires specifying the exacly numer of decimal places. Example: exp(1, x) returns the the euler number with x decimals places, precisely. So I've to rougly estimate this number to compute the exponentiation precisely up to a given scale. I tried estimatiing using log10, but for fractional powers it does not work.

Comment: So it's absolute error scale. That's problematic, because it means you have to estimate the answer in order to estimate how accurate the exponent must be. It is probably easier to proceed iteratively: get the answer with a prespecified relative error (say $10^{-16}$ a la double precision floating point), then determine whether that was good enough for your absolute error scale, if not then continue improving it.

Comment: (Cont.) Determining how to get a relative error of at most $10^{-16}$ is not hard using the Lagrange remainder and the trivial identity $\exp(-x)=1/\exp(x)$: assume without loss of generality that $x \geq 0$ and then just continue adding Taylor terms until $x^{n+1}/(n+1)!<10^{-16}$.

Comment: For $x$ close to zero, some libraries provide special routines for computing $e^x-1$ and $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I still don't know the scale for the ln and mul, right? These values are the input of the exp function. If they are not precise enough, the result will still be wrong.

Comment: Btw, both ln and exp are already computed iteratively using Taylor series, producing resuts with a given scale (precise up to the last digit). I believe the problem here is determining the scale for ln and exp so tha the result will be precise up to a given decimal place.